# GNOME Shell Theme css documentation

Tags: css, themes, gnome-shell

Where can I find documentation about the GNOME Shell theme css elements?
For instance, if I want to change the style of the "Activites" which css class/id do I have to tweak?
More in general I'm looking for somethings that maps each gnome shell element to its class / id in the css

Thanks!

Comment: Does this help? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1479239

Comment: ...unfortunately not... It's stuff I already knew... I'm looking for mapping information. Thanks anyways

Comment: Is there any recent development in this area?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I still cannot find documentation, however by looking into other themes I could finally find what I was looking for this specific case.

```
#panelActivities
```

is the style to tweak

Answer (score 13):

This might be a little dated, but I was able to track down a somewhat authoratiative source. Starting with the documentation that turns up for developing on gnome shell:

https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Development

The CSS section mentions that the theme stuff is located in `gnome-shell/source/gnome-shell/data/theme/gnome-shell.css`. Of course, it doesn't give a link or anything. From there, I googled for the source code, picked a reasonably recent version and hoped that I could browse the code using the path in the documentation. Lo and behold, the CSS!

https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-shell/tree/data/theme/gnome-shell.css?h=gnome-3-18

In my case, I wanted to make all of the font smaller but I didn't know what the root element was. I was able to determine that `stage` is what I should target with something like `font-size: 0.8em` in my custom theme in `~/.themes/Naddeo/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css`. This is my entire CSS file in case someone else is trying a real theme but they want to override one or two things. To use it, just pick it in the gnome tweak tool as your shell theme.

```
@import url("/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css");

stage {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    height: 1.50em;
}
```